# Replace strings from column with unique random strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, random

I have a a csv that has multiple columns, one of these columns consists of strings.

I start with just reading the csv file and then just using two columns

```
df = pd.read_csv("MyDATA_otherstring.csv", usecols=["describe_file", "data_numbers"])
```

This is the output

```
    describe_file   data_numbers
0   This is the start of the story  7309.0
1   This is the start of the story  35.0
2   This is the start of the story  302.0
3   Difficult part  7508.5
4   Difficult part  363.0
```

In around 10k rows, there are around 150 unique strings. These strings appear  multiple times within the file.

My goal
Filter by the first string example 'This is is the start of the story' and replace it with a random string.

I want to run over all the strings in that column and replace them with unique strings

I have looked into the random library and some questions that have been asked here, unfortunately I have not found anything that would help me.

Comment: Please be more specific about what research you have done, and what you’ve tried. You could at the very least provide the data in a more convenient or practical format.

Answer (score 1):

This is your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame([['This is the start of the story']*3 + ['Difficult part']*2, 
    np.random.rand(5)], index=['describe_file', 'data_numbers']).T
```

```
                    describe_file data_numbers
0  This is the start of the story     0.825913
1  This is the start of the story     0.704422
2  This is the start of the story      0.91563
3                  Difficult part     0.192693
4                  Difficult part     0.795088
```

This is how you can do it:

```
df.describe_file = df.join(df.groupby('describe_file')['describe_file'].apply(lambda x:
    ''.join(np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), 10))), \
    on='describe_file', rsuffix='_NEW')['describe_file_NEW']
```

The result:

```
  describe_file data_numbers
0    skgfdrsktw     0.204907
1    skgfdrsktw     0.399947
2    skgfdrsktw     0.990196
3    rziuoslpqn     0.930852
4    rziuoslpqn     0.210122
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I was trying to find something that would do this with all the string. If I have to cope and paste into the code every string. I won't safe more than than just doing the find and replace option in excel

Comment: like this? (see answer). i.e., make random strings for an entire column?

Comment: And "the string "this is the start of story" should be replaced by one strong not Everytime a different one

Comment: Example. All the "this is the start of the story" replace with with "kkbim" . All the " difficult part" replace them by some other string

Comment: got it. hope this is what you're expecting (see edit)

Comment: I tried the second part of the code , however I am getting the  following error ``` Keyerror:  describe_file_NEW ```

Comment: The code runs fine on the example provided. Maybe try `df = ...` instead of `df.describe_file = ...` and remove `['describe_file_NEW']` at the end

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by @Nicolas Gervais is fine, but after reading several times the question I interpret that the question is to replace 'This is the part of the story' by a random string, but leave the rest 'Difficult part' as it is. The following command including `.replace()` statement is doing that.

```
df['describe_file'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('This is the start of the story', ''.join(np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), 10))))
```

```
0        glhrtqwlnl
1        qxrklnxhoj
2        kszgtysptj
3    Difficult part
4    Difficult part
Name: describe_file, dtype: object
```